# SQL запрос для простой рекомендательной системы.

Tags: sql

Каждая запись в таблице **movies** имеет:

**user** - пользователь
   **movie**    - фильм
           **rating** - рейтинг данного пользователя для данного фильма

Пользователь **1** хочет получить рекомендации (то есть список фильмов) от группы пользователей **2,3,4,5,6,7**.

Полученные фильмы НЕ должны встречаться среди фильмов пользователя **1** и
  должны иметь средний рейтинг в данной группе пользователей не меньше чем **3**. При этом фильмы, которые посмотрело менее 3-х человек из группы, не могут быть рекомендованы.

Вот мой вариант, но он не отражает последнего требования:

```
SELECT t2.movie
FROM movies t1 INNER JOIN movies t2
     ON t1.user = 1
     AND t2.user IN(2,3,4,5,6,7)
     AND t2.movie NOT IN ( SELECT movie
                           FROM movies
                           WHERE user = 1 )
  GROUP BY(t2.movie)
  HAVING AVG(t2.rating)>=3
```

Пробовал добавлять перед группировкой вот это:

```
AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.user, t2.movie)>3
```

Пишет, что неправильно использую группы.
           Как же отфильтровать результаты, которые встречаются в группе менее 3-х раз?

Comment: Сделай скрипт Sql который создает БД c записями, тогда решится проблема быстрее :)

Comment: Условие отбора с агрегатной функцией не может использоваться в секции WHERE, которая выполняется до группировки. Разместите условие в секции HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.movie
FROM movies t1 INNER JOIN movies t2
     ON t1.user = 1
     AND t2.user IN(2,3,4,5,6,7)
     AND t2.movie NOT IN ( SELECT movie
                           FROM movies
                           WHERE user = 1 )
GROUP BY(t2.movie)
HAVING AVG(t2.rating)>=3 
AND  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.user) >= 3
```